# Is it possible to connect eight digital inputs to a digital output?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, fpga, clock, clock-speed

Can eight digital inputs (at 20-Mhz) output to 160-Mhz? Does a multiplexer work for this? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: "(at 20-Mhz) output to 160-Mhz?" Say what now?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: This technique is called *time multiplex*.

Comment: the easy way to do this is by instantiate an asynchronous fifo, and clock in the 8-bit 20 mhz signals on the write side of the fifo and to read the 8 signals on 120 mhz side of the async fifo.  This is assuming that all 8-bit are already synchronized to the same 20 mhz clock.

Comment: Alternatively, If you don't care about the 8-bit signals potentially getting out of synch with each other by a cycle at 160 mhz, then you can just clock them with two flip-flops in a row at 180 mhz... the signals will be safe to use in 180 mhz domain after this synchronization stage... if you need to generate enable signal at 160 mhz... add a 9-bit bit to get synchronized that is fed by a toggle a bit at 20 mhz for each valid step of the data...then covert toggle to a pulse at 160mhz every time it changes values... you might want to delay this valid signal by a cycle or two to realign bits..

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the digital inputs. If each individual digital channel is the same digital protocol (frames). Then you can apply a process called "Muxing". This we take your 8 paralleled lines of data, then apply it to a device called a parallel to serial shift register (74HC589 for example)  then you frame it out back to you eight data lines. These of IC's are based off the device known as a flip-flop. See: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_5.html as they go into great detail in construction and operation.